# How to add multipart/mixed MIME boundary in Content-Type header in Swagger

Tags: mime-types, swagger, swagger-ui

In Swagger UI, is there a way to supply a MIME boundary that can be included in the `Content-Type` header?

Using Swagger, I can generate / submit different content types in Swagger UI by using the `consumes` property in the Swagger Spec, e.g. `application/json`, `application/xml`, etc. However, I need to supply a MIME boundary that may be different per request. For example, in the following Content-Type header from RFC 2049, it would be preferable for the unique boundary value to be input in the UI as a text field. Is there anyway to indicate this in the Spec?

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=unique-boundary-1
```

Comment: Why would you need to define that as part of the UI? That should be generated automatically by the ui.

Comment: If I use `"consumes" : ["multipart/mixed"]`, the UI is currently sending `multipart/mixed; charset=UTF-8` and not extracting the boundary string out of the body parameter. Is there something I need to do for the UI to automatically parse it out of the body and include it in the `Content-Type` header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't currently supported and has been accepted as an possible enhancement in the Swagger.Next Proposal on Github:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/issues/303